# Grid gain: Tracking worker tasks from gateway

Tags: gridgain

We are using grid gain to execute some of our tasks in application.
Grid gain setup includes 3 gateways and each gateway has 3 workers. 
At times while debugging issues we want to be able to track gateway allocates job to which worker but gateway logs show the job ID but we cannot find it in worker logs.

How do we link Job ID of task in gateway with worker task.

Answer (score 0):

You can track task execution using system events: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events

In particular, you can subscribe to all events in `EventType.EVTS_JOB_EXECUTION` collection and add logging in the listener.